# getting rid of nbsp

Tags: html, html-entities

Help, Im really sick of using this lots of nbsps in my results page. Im just a  beginner. Can you recommend me some techniques so that I will not be copy pasting this lots of nbsp just to get the space and line breaks I need.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "Patient #:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['PNUM']; 

     echo "<B>"."Hospital #:"."</B>". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['HOSPNUM']."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;";
      echo "<B>"."Room:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['ROOMNUM'];
       echo "<B>"."Lastname:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['LASTNAME'];
        echo "<B>"."Firstname:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['FIRSTNAME'];
         echo "<B>"."Middlename:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['MIDNAME'];
          echo "<B>"."Admission Date:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['ADATE'];
           echo "<B>"."Admission Time:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['ADTIME'];
                echo "<B>"."Patient #:". "&nbsp;".  "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". "&nbsp;". $row['PNUM']; 

      }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: If you are using `&nbsp;` to format columns to present *data*, thats mistake number one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it have to be plain text or can you display this in a [table](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/tables/)?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Patient #</th>
    <th>Hospital #</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <!-- etc. -->
</tr>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row['PNUM']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['HOSPNUM']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['ROOMNUM']</td>";
    // etc.
    echo "</tr>";
}
</table>
```

Comment: HTML injection (XSS). Needs `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 9):

Use a HTML [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) tag.

Answer (score 4):

Consider tables or definition lists

Answer (score 1):

if your output is mainly for debugging, you can output your results in `pre` tag, pre tag, **pre**serve space and line breaks

if not, you should learn some html (and css), a few possibilities are lists, tables, or custom markup with css style